# Custom table is not shown properly when scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

For some reason my custom table cell is not shown properly when scrolled. Anything I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RestaurantCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RestaurantCell
    cell.name?.text = "Some test value"

    return cell
}
```

And here is how it looks:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have constraint issues in the storyboard/xib you're using for the cells.

Comment: I have constraints, but why does it work for some of the cells and for some it doesn't?

Comment: When there are constraint issues, the runtime will try to correct them by breaking some of the constraints you've set or adding new ones. That way the end result is undefined. Take a look at the debug console to see if it shows auto layout issues.

Comment: No layout warnings and I do not add any constraint programatically, so I still do not understand how some cells look OK and some are not...

Comment: Eventually deleting the cell, recreating it and assigning the constraints in the EXACTLY the same way fix this strange issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following the above answer, Ive mistakenly added views to the cell directly instead of the cell.contentView. This could also cause constraint issues

Comment: I added a cell and on that cell I put a label. All using the storyboard. Anything wrong here?