# Constraint issue with UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints

I simply want to center a `UILabel` in my `UITableViewCell`.
I set the following constraints:

- Trailing space: 10
- Leading space: 10
- Top space to: 10

For some of the cells I am getting this error:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>           Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
>           Try this: 
>               (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
>               (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
>       (
>           "",
>           "",
>           ""
>       )

And the label seems to be off the cell (the cell is empty).

Here is how the constraints look like:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: have you set height constraint for label? and possible then please share screenshot for constraint (all should expanded) from xib

Comment: You need to set height constraint.

Comment: can you please share your project or some code?

Comment: I don't think this is caused by the lack of a height constraint.  That would cause a warning that appears once.  Rather, I think this is due to actual conflicting constraints.  Is your label constrained to the content view of the table cell or the table cell itself?  It should be the former.  Some beta versions of Xcode 5, for example, did the latter, and you'd have to move them manually.  But I doubt you're still on an Xcode 5 beta. :)  Can you post your exact error, with all the constraints that it can't simultaneously satisfy?

Comment: I added height constraint on the label: Height equals: 21. It doesn't help.

Comment: @Sohil R. Memon, I do not think code can help here. This is a constraints issue. All these things are done on the story board. If you are still interested in seeing some code, I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599781/custom-table-is-not-shown-properly-when-scrolled

Comment: @eric, I posed a screenshot from the storyboard. Can you please let me know if you see something wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious, although as others have mentioned it would be useful on iOS 8+ to constrain the bottom of the label to the bottom of the content view.  Could you post the full error text, including all the constraints that contributed to the solver failure, rather than just `( "", "", "" )`?

Comment: Thanks @eric, eventually what solved this issue was deleting the cell and doing EXACTLY the same of what I was doing and all seemed to work OK.

Comment: OK, how odd!  Glad you worked it out in the end. :)

Answer (score 2):

Delete your original three constraints and use the align constraints to set the horizontal and vertical in container alignments to 0.

[image]

Comment: I tried this constraint and it also doesn't work. Anyway, I will need to add more controls to the cell, so just centering it isn't going to be enough...

Comment: Just curious but when you say it didn't work did Xcode give an error or did it not centre the UILabel correctly?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a very productive response. What is going wrong, do they not center, do you get errors, do they fly out of the window? Anyway, in your question you say that you "simply want to center", now you are saying you want something else. What is it?

Comment: Sorry @fishinear, it would have been harder to explain if I was telling the whole thing I would like to accomplish. When I wrote that it doesn't work I meant that I see the same effect. Some cells look OK some not. Eventually what solved this issue was deleting the cell and doing EXACTLY the same of what I was doing and all seemed to work OK.